# Extracting URL query string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use Javascript to extract the "code" parameter from the URL.

Can anyone tell me why the javascript that I wrote below does not print the query string on the HTML page?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

URL: google.com?code=123456789

HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>

Your code is:
<script>
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
    var code = getUrlVars()["code"];
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to move function invocation outside of the function declaration. To begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {},  //you need object aka hash not an array
        hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        //you need to decode uri components
        vars[decodeURIComponent(hash[0])] = decodeURIComponent(hash[1]);
    }
    return vars;

}

//you need to call the function outside of its declaration
var code = getUrlVars()["code"]; 
document.write(code); //immediate write to document
or: console.log(code); //log to console
```